# Track time spent reading an email

Tags: php, email, tracking

To track opens on emails we usually include a blank pixel image (1x1px) which actually executes a backend code.
Is there any way to track time spent on email? One could save the timestamp for the open event, but how do you get the timestamp when user close the window/tab? For example, using PHP session, how would you log session times in this scenario?

Comment: Given that email clients nowadays usually block online images I wouldn't set my hopes to high to get a reliable solution even for the starting timestamp let alone for end timestamp.

Comment: Javascript is not unable on some users' browser but we still use Google Analytics.

Comment: You are aware that Google Analytics just the same relies on a tracking pixel that is likely to be blocked. There's no magic solution.

Answer (score 0):

> **This is not an answer; this is a statement as to why this question can not (as of June 2019) be answered with any degree of certainty.**

## Issue 1: Getting the data

**Email clients will block data transport or will offer blocking**

Over the last couple of years everyone has got very tetchy about being "tracked", and this has caused various email clients to add various "gateways" to stop - or at least give the email owner the choice - as to if they want to load external content.

My experience with Thunderbird (market share 1% as of May 2019) is that the **email client** will ask the user if they want to load external resources (images, JS or CSS files, etc.).

This can also be easily achieved with Gmail (market share 29% as of May 2019) and  with *most* other email clients, either through *user-set-* or *default-* settings.

**non-HTML emails**

Non-HTML emails (through which all emails can be displayed, at the users disgression) will not be able to track user opening or loading an email in the classic sense (ie with image injection as used by Google Analytics as of May 2019).

**People will, going forward, be more likely use these offered blocking services**

Due to the passage of time, people who are less familiar with email clients, (ie old folks) will fall off the demographics and younger people will join the demographic spread. As people are now much more aware and generally competent with digital technology as well as being much more aware of the perceived risks of being "tracked", the percentage of people who actively seek out blocking of data transport (such as loading external images) is going to increase in the future.

**What does this mean?**

There is a significant margin of error even getting the source data, before even starting to use that data to dig into *how the data changes over time* (ie how long the email was open for).

## Issue 2: Understanding the Data (or lack thereof)

So say that you have a percentage of emails that do give data feedback, these are HTML emails that are opened with all external resources loaded.

Even in this situation; all you have is a flag that the email has been opened/read. You could *possibly* run some sort of Javascript (AJAX) so for instance every 10 seconds run a script and check if the image is still being requested by the endpoint (the email client), however that means nothing as it does not correlate at all to the intended recipient actually reading the message.

Also it is absolutely worth noting that javascript in emails is almost universally blocked by default and it would suffer a much lower execution rate than even loading an image.

Any process employed (that I can think of) that can reliably give feedback times will have either large potential errors or large error margins in the results given and therfore completely undermining the validity of any results generated.

The Server can not reliable track the access times for the locally held [image] file because email clients will also cache external content so that if an email is opened, then the images / files are downloaded and then the email is closed, when it is opened again in the future, the *cached* assets are loaded and your tracking server will not be contacted.

## Issue 3: Understanding the fluidity of email

There are many issue with emails in general. One of the biggest is their almost complete lack of security. Any server that has an email on it can have that email read by anyone with server access rights, so for any server there can be anything from a few to dozens of people who could read that email *without the recipient being aware*.

There is also an issue that emails can be duplicated and copied at will (automatically or in various other ways), through the natural course of email processing. With servers located across the globe for larger firms (Google, Hotmail, Apple) it is completely legitimate that an email can load an `<img>` tag from Google Analytics while never being delivered to - or separately, never being read by - the intended recipient.

There is also almost no way of confirming that the correct end user reading the email is the same person who signed up for the email.

## Summary

- You have no guarentee that the email will be read by the intended recipient.
- You have a potentially significant error margin in any present day detection of email opening (no data returned at all).
- You have a potentially significant error margin in getting "false positives" from server admin, server debug code, ani-virus and other automated processes following the links in the email. There is a huge number of risks of false positives due to email copying and tracing activities.
- Successful timing initiators can easily become high load for your server (depending on email list size) and give high error margins on any results found.
- Your server doing the timing counts can very easily be marked as spam and be blocked by spamlists due to the activity of "timing" an email read.

So you can get some results, but the margin of errors of i) number of results and ii) quality of the results given would result in (my opinion) an error margin so big it's going to be worthless to use the data retrieved.

## As soon as an email leaves your system, you can trust absolutely nothing about it.

*Please edit and update this question if there are new items or details to include.*

Comment: If a database is qualified and users are waiting for emails then yes, most of these users will have the image loading enabled on their email client/webmail. Original question was How can it be done, not why it should not.

Comment: It can not be done. You may as well ask how to get man to visit jupitar. Yes, you can get a *human body* to Jupitar but not a live being. You can get time stamps but they will be so wildly inaccurate they will be worthless.